# Why explain plan uses INDEX UNIQUE SCAN and TABLE ACCESS FULL?

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

I query a view that is built from 3 tables. The main tables are joined by a column that in table A it is indexed & in table B it is PK.
The view has additional column that is used in the condition but it is not indexed.
seems a simple query from the table is using the primary key but also accesses the table with table access full.
I need an explanation as to why this happens & how to make it better.
Tabc in the example code below is very small & therefore expected to be accessed full.

```
create or replace view v_per_pda
as select cola, colb, case when colc = 51 then colc else 0 end decd
from taba, tabb, tabc
where taba.id = tabb.id
and tabb.cold = 1
and taba.id2 = tabc.id2
```

in the explain plan below you can see :
taba is accesses by index range scan & tabb is accesses by the primary key
the table access full below relates to table b.
why does oracle uses this?

[image]

Comment: just to be clear, tabc in the explain plan is accesed by index range scan as well. the bottom one.

Comment: Please post the execution plan as text including table names and predicates. See[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) for details.

Comment: I did what you asked but it gives me a different execution plan. I would like to re-check this.

Answer (score 0):

I consulted a DBA & what the pl sql developer shows is adaptive explain plan after executing the explain plan using plan_table - you do not see the table access full. moreover, it is more accurate.

so thank you & this question is a closed issue